# I don't under the reason for this error in the print_output function

Tags: python

I don't under the reason for this error in the print_output function. This may be an issue with the other functions. I am not sure what the formatting error is.

'''

```
 def print_output(i):
   print (f"OUTPUT {i}")

 def triangle_hypotenuse(side_1, side_2):
   sqrt((side_1 ** 2) + (side_2 ** 2)) = h
   h = "{:.2f}".format(h)
   print_output(h)

 def feet_to_meters(feet):
   meters = feet/3.281
   meters = "{:.4f}".format(meters)
   print_output(meters)

 def polar_coords(x,y):
   radius = math.sqrt( x * x + y * y )
   theta = math.atan(y/x)
   theta = 180 * theta/math.pi
   r = "{:.2f}".format(radius)
   t = "{:.2f}".format(theta)
   phrase_1 = "r: " + r
   phrase_2 = "theta: " + t
   combined = phrase_1 + phrase_2
   print_output(combined)

 def dollars_to_euros(dollars):
   euros = dollars * 0.99
   euros = "{:.2f}".format(dollars)
   print_output(euros

Error : 
 >>> print_output("Hello World")
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
print_output("Hello World")
NameError: name 'print_output' is not defined
```

'''

Comment: You appear to have run a single line of code in the shell, without having first run any of the code you've showed to actually define the functions.

Comment: Make sure your functions have already been defined and your code is well indented. Also the last line is missing a parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Create a txt file and name it to "myfile.py". Make sure your file extension has been changed from .txt to .py. Then paste the following in that python file which you can open with either an IDE or notepad.

```
import math
def print_output(i):
   print (f"OUTPUT {i}")

def triangle_hypotenuse(side_1, side_2):
   h = math.sqrt((side_1 ** 2) + (side_2 ** 2))
   h = "{:.2f}".format(h)
   print_output(h)

def feet_to_meters(feet):
   meters = feet/3.281
   meters = "{:.4f}".format(meters)
   print_output(meters)

def polar_coords(x,y):
   radius = math.sqrt( x * x + y * y )
   theta = math.atan(y/x)
   theta = 180 * theta/math.pi
   r = "{:.2f}".format(radius)
   t = "{:.2f}".format(theta)
   phrase_1 = "r: " + r
   phrase_2 = "theta: " + t
   combined = phrase_1 + phrase_2
   print_output(combined)

def dollars_to_euros(dollars):
   euros = dollars * 0.99
   euros = "{:.2f}".format(dollars)
   print_output(euros)
if __name__ == "__main__":
   print_output("Hello World")
```

Now in the address bar where the python file exists, type CMD and press enter
[as shown in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSRM3.png)

In the command terminal, type `python myfile.py` and your python file will execute

Comment: What's the point of the external link?

Comment: It's just an image which shows where to type in CMD command in the file explorer. I thought it would show that image in the answer but it seems to have given a hyperlink instead

Comment: It is probably being assumed, but at the beginning of your program code include "import math" and "from math import sqrt" so that the square root and trig commands work.  Alternatively, one can just enter "import math" and change the call of "sqrt" to "math.sqrt".  Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed he wrote a proper indented code with imported libraries. I have edited my answer to reflect that now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to my VSCode's Python Extension, there are multiple issues in this code. I tried to correct the errors:

```
import math


def print_output(i):
   print (f"OUTPUT {i}")

def triangle_hypotenuse(side_1, side_2):
   h = math.sqrt((side_1 ** 2) + (side_2 ** 2))
   h = "{:.2f}".format(h)
   print_output(h)

def feet_to_meters(feet):
   meters = feet/3.281
   meters = "{:.4f}".format(meters)
   print_output(meters)

def polar_coords(x,y):
   radius = math.sqrt( x * x + y * y )
   theta = math.atan(y/x)
   theta = 180 * theta/math.pi
   r = "{:.2f}".format(radius)
   t = "{:.2f}".format(theta)
   phrase_1 = "r: " + r
   phrase_2 = "theta: " + t
   combined = phrase_1 + phrase_2
   print_output(combined)

def dollars_to_euros(dollars):
   euros = dollars * 0.99
   euros = "{:.2f}".format(dollars)
   print_output(euros)


print_output("Hello World")
```

Corrections:

1. I am not sure if it is due to copy-paste, but the indication is wrong for the time being. The first space character before each line had to be removed.
2. The expression `sqrt((side_1 ** 2) + (side_2 ** 2)) = h` is invalid.
3. There is a `)` missing at the end of the function `dollars_to_euros`.

Answer (score 0):

To run your function the computer needs to know where to look for it. If you run the functions straight in the command line will not work unless you have written the function there too.

You have probably saved your code in a file, for example test.py. Add this at the top or at the bottom of the code. And run the file either in your interpreter (vscode, intellij, pycharm, python's own or whatever).

```
def print_output(i):
   print (f"OUTPUT {i}")
.
.
.
print_output("hello")
```